# Reflect WF4 System.Activities

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, reflector, workflow-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reflector Not Decompiling 'System.Data.Entity.dll' .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239320/reflector-not-decompiling-system-data-entity-dll-net-4-0)

I want to reflect the WF4 System.Activities assembly.

The problem is when i open it in the reflector all the methods are empty!

I can reflect the WF3 System.Activities...

Does any one know if i can reflect it?

Comment: I'd answer, but I already did answer this.

Comment: Thank you Will, it's exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is but it's certainly possible. I use Reflector all the time to check on the WF4 activities internals.