# Does HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse uses blocking GetResponse on thread pool in WP7 or Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, http, rest, networking

I'm porting Android application that uses REST API to WP7 platform.

In Android all of REST API calls are blocking and I manually use Executors to balance threads doing network I/O.

In WP7 and Silverlight I have to use HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse and it has only async variant of reading response.

Is it:

1) Uses something like I/O Asynchronous Completion and it's really async?
or
2) Just uses blocking read / write operations inside + thread behind it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you ask? Does it matter?

Comment: As I said before: Im porting existing Android's application code that uses blocking reading + thread pool for network requests balancing, I think to port Java's ThreadPoolExecutor to WP7 and use my Java code with minimum changes, but if WP7's async I/O methods are not really async (use hidden blocking reading + thread) -> ported WP7 application could have a performance issues that i want to avoid (will be 2 threads running at the same time instead of 1 for one pending REST method). Having big count of threads for phone application is bad practice, even if they idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the source code using Reflector, it's a blocking call executed on the thread pool.

```
public override IAsyncResult BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    this.startGetResponse();
    LazyAsyncResult result = new LazyAsyncResult(this, state, callback);
    if (!ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(this.asyncGetResponse), result, true))
    {
        throw new OutOfMemoryException(SR.GetString(0x49, new object[0]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how did you get this decompiled sources? When i decompile Silverlight assembly i see only stubs in methods (like throw NotImplementedException());

Comment: @gorecode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239320/reflector-not-decompiling-system-data-entity-dll-net-4-0/3399222#3399222

Comment: Will is right on the "those assemblies only contain metadata" part. Unfortunately the full assembly isn't available directly with the SDK (it's stored directly in the emulator image). The assemblies can be extracted from the image using dumping tools. You can find more information on the Xda-Developers forums.

Comment: I'm not 100% percent sure that it's so on real devices. Emulator could use "customized" build. I'll try to examine it with manual test on real device and 'll post answer here.